# How to add a button in KeystoneJs Admin GUI to call function

Tags: keystonejs

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a button in the KeystonJs admin for example in the User model. I would like to have a set of fields and enable an admin to click "Add another" which will create a new field/row of fields.

So I just want that button to call a function. Something like this:

```
{ addItem: { type: Types.Button, label: 'Add another', actions: addItem() }}},
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a button on KeystoneJs Admin GUI, you have to modify and build upon its's source. There is no way you can do that in this release (4.0).

There are discussions on their GitHub issues page and it may land in next version but no promises made yet.